# Установка кукисов, которые должны отправляться каждым запросом

Tags: php, cookie

Я не понимаю эту строку:
cookie = 'Session_id=3:1418046935.5.0.1401987771000';

Это уже прочитал:
http://php.net/manual/ru/features.cookies.php
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-id.php

> session_id() используется для получения или установки идентификатора
>   текущей сессии.

1) Что эти числа 3:1418046935.5.0.1401987771000 означают?

2) Бывает еще вот такое:
 "session_id" : "372276a0279caee08057ff61d1d173c9b74c76374ab8742354f2407d909da3e93b944e7fef90bb56cdddb40224aba3bbb54a148a6a859fb641af5cf90ce97"

3) И самый главный вопрос, который меня больше всего интересует, можно ли написать в session_id число, чтобы браузер думал, что я нахожусь, например, в России и предпочитаю читать страницы в интернете на русском языке?

Comment: "что за число" - рандомное число, ид сессии (уникальный номер (идентификатор)). "бывает такое..." - зашифрованный ид сессии (наверное, чтобы не повторялся ид сессии). "можно ли написать..." - нельзя (формально можно, но, наверное, нежелательно), ид сессии устанавливается автоматически. лучше передавай число в куках.

Answer (score 1):

1 и 2: собственно ничего. Это просто набор случайных символов, что бы отличать одного пользователя от другого.

3: язык не определяется через session_id, обычно он определяется на основании IP или языка ОС, а потом - предположение о языке может заноситься (а может нет) в сессию.

Answer (score 1):

Расскажу проведя аналогию, скажем, с секретным заводом!

Твой **сервер и сайт на нём - это секретное предприятие, завод**. На него то и дело приходят туристы, сотрудники и боссы. Все они проходят через охрану на проходной. Каждый такой **проход на территорию завода - это как запрос к сайту**.

Но все люди разные и их много. Поэтому охранники на входе каждому входящему человеку дарят бесплатную фирменную футболку! Белую и чистую. И пишут на ней что им самим хочется. Если человек пришёл без футболки - дарят, если пришёл уже в ней - читают надписи на ней, стирают старые и дописывают новые. В итоге толпы людей ходят на завод и обратно, и у каждого фирменная футболка исписанная всякими каракулями. Так вот, **футболка в случае работы сайта - это и есть заголовок запроса, в котором хранятся в том числе и куки**.

При этом у самого охранника на проходной на столе лежит супер-секретный журнал посещений. Если человек пришёл на завод впервые, то охранник проверяет его паспорт, пропуск, отпечатки пальцев и сетчатку глаза. Сравнивает всё это с тем, что хранится у кадровиков и hr'ов. А для этого бежит лично к ним в отдел, копается в архивах, ящиках и столах, пока не найдёт нужные записи и не сравнит их. Если человек не имеет права пройти на завод, охранник его прогоняет. А вот если имеет, то тут-то нам и нужен секретный журнал посещений! Охранник достаёт из ящика стола игральные кости, обычные кубики, бросает их, скажем, 100 раз, и получает длинную последовательность чисел `13622415233416...`. Это число охранник вписывает в свой секретный журнал посещений. Напротив числа вписывает всё, что ему лично пригодится знать о посетителе в будущем, и ради чего он бы не хотел снова бежать в отдел к бухгалтерам и hr'ам. А затем это же самое число охранник пишет чёрным маркером на футболке посетителя. И только потом пропускает его внутрь. Так вот! Длинное **случайное число в случае работы сайта - это и есть id сессии**. А те **секретные данные, что охранник вписал в журнал - данные сессии которым можно доверять**, они хранятся у вас на сервере, а у охранника в журнале к которому имеет доступ только он. **Отдел бухгалтеров и hr'ов в случае сайта - база данных**, кэши или удалённый сервис авторизации, место, где вы храните и проверяете логин и пароль. Так работает **аутентификация** - выяснение, кто же перед нами с помощью детальной проверки.

Если посетитель пришёл снова и он уже носит футболку и на ней уже написано некое огромное число, то охранник берёт журнал и ищет в нём такое число. Если его нет, то скорее всего футболку пора постирать. Быть может эту футболку вообще украли! Или купили в магазине за углом чистую, а потом написали на ней случайное число наугад. Если же число найдено, то никаких дополнительных проверок делать почти и не надо. Можно сразу пропустить человека на завод. Заодно узнать из записи в журнале, как его зовут, в каком отделе он работает, не босс ли он случайно и т.д. Так работает **идентификация** - определение, кто же перед нами без проверки всех данных вообще.

Если при этом право перемещения по этажам и цехам завода требует отдельного индивидуального пропуска, и он хранится у охранника, и выдаётся по утрам в начале работы и отбирается у сотрудника вечером, то мы получаем то, что называется **авторизацией** - проверкой прав на конкретные действия.

Продолжаем аналогию и отвечаем на ваши вопросы. Теперь про геопозицию.

В один прекрасный день на завод приезжает делегация из-за границы. Это становится понятно после проверки документов. Туристов можно пропустить, но им нужен сопровождающий переводчик (на сайте вы бы, например, автоматически выбрали нужную локаль и язык сайта). Но охранник не дурак и не хочет каждый раз для этой огромной кучи гостей выяснять откуда они и нужен ли им переводчик. Поэтому он просто пишет на футболке каждого "турист заморский, одна штука". Либо (!! и это важно) пишет тоже самое в своём секретном журнале.

Важно понимать, что **футболка - это куки браузера**, а **журнал охранника - это приватные данные бэкэнда** сайта. Тому, что написано на футболке, доверять нельзя. Каждый раз, когда охранник читает текст с футболки, он кривит морду лица и выглядит как [собака-подозревака](https://yandex.ru/images/search?text=%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0). Каждый раз ему приходится проверять, не пытаются ли его обмануть, не написал ли человек надпись на футболке сам. Зато всему, что написано в журнале, доверять можно.

Если в следующий раз на пороге появится посетитель с меткой "турист" и этим данным можно доверять (они не критичны в случае фальсификации), то охранник просто сразу позовёт гида-переводчика.

Из всего вышесказанного следует интересный вывод. Сессия в том виде в котором она есть в `php` из коробки - даром никому не нужна. Вы всегда можете сами создать сессию и управлять ею по своему желанию. При этом у вас даже есть выбор, как именно действовать. Если вы привыкли к функциям `session_*` или поддерживаете код, в котором они уже были до вас, то попробуйте написать свои реализации для этих функций перехватив управление с помощью [session_set_save_handler](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-set-save-handler.php) (так, например, можно хранить данные сессии не в файловой системе а-ля журнал охранника, а прямо в памяти - мемкеш или редис сгодятся). Либо, просто выбросьте всё с этим связанное и сами генерите уникальный `id` и сами добавляйте куку с его значением пользователю после успешной аутентификации. И сами решайте где на сервере хранить этот `id` и как его потом искать. Это будет та же самая сессия, но вы будете её контролировать от и до, и лучше понимать как она устроена.

Пара слов о безопасности. В примере с заводом и футболками становится очевидным, что футболку можно сделать самостоятельно. Или украсть у другого работника завода. Можно даже не красть, а подсмотреть номер написанный на футболке в бинокль и, когда работник уйдёт домой, надеть такую же футболку и прибежать на завод. Тоже самое происходит в случае кражи кук и сессионных данных из них. Что же можно сделать?

Во-первых охранник в своём журнале может в отдельное поле записывать приметы сотрудника. Например, "голубые глаза, хромает на правую ногу, проплешина на голове". Теперь, когда секретный номер проверен и запись в журнале найдена, охранник дополнительно быстро и дёшево проверит остальные признаки. Найдёт несовпадения - выгонит самозванца. Да ещё на всякий случай вычеркнет запись об этом пользователе из журнала как скомпрометированную. В реальной жизни такими признаками могут быть, например, версия браузера, разрешение экрана, ip-адрес и т.п.

Во-вторых обмен данными может идти по зашифрованному каналу, что сильно усложнит кражу. В примере с заводом, надписи на футболке можно делать с внутренней стороны. Подходишь к охраннику, задираешь футболку и он смотрит что там у тебя снизу. В реальной жизни это будет `https` вместо `http`.

В третьих т.к. id сессии хранится в куках, можно не показывать всем свои куки установив для них флаг `http-only`. В этом случае они не будут доступны на стороне клиента через javascript. Но будут по прежнему отправляться в запросах на сервер. В случае с заводом охранник может попросить посетителя запомнить длинный уникальный номер, а не записывать его на футболке. Люди будут сообщать номер по памяти уже на проходной. Конечно, всё ещё можно заняться ректальной криптографией и узнать секретный код. В реальном мире можно прослушать трафик, заразить жертву трояном и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

1. это идентификатор сессии он сам генерируется
2. сессия хранит то что ты туда передашь в ней не хранится язык ресурс может понять какой язык в зависимости от того как реализована проверка